# Filtering DataFrame with static date value

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to filter DataFrame to get all dates greater than '2012-09-15'
I tried the solution from another post which suggested me to use

```
data.filter(data("date").lt(lit("2015-03-14")))
```

but i am getting an error

> TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

What is the solution for this

Comment: filter can also take sql expression. try `data.filter("date>'2012-09-15'")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need square brackets around "date", i.e.

```
data.filter(data["date"] < lit("2015-03-14"))
```

Calling `data("date")` is treating `data` as a function (rather than a dataframe)

Comment: now im getting TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: ah yeah, I'd recommend just using the `<` operator. Updated my answer to use that.